# Excel vba to read data from a oracle database which was set to readonly

Tags: database, excel, vba

I am trying to read data from oracle using adodb connection object from excel.But I am getting an error " oracle -160000 database was set to read only access".Please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: Updated post with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the recordset open method's LockType parameter and use adLockReadOnly. I'm not familiar with Oracle. You may also need to CursorType parameter to adOpenForwardOnly.

Example:

```
Dim lobjADOConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim lobjADOData As ADODB.Recordset
Dim lstrSQL As String

Set lobjADOConnection = New ADODB.Connection
lobjADOConnection.Open ...

Set lobjADOData = New ADODB.Recordset

lstrSQL = "<your query here>"

lobjADOData.Open lstrSQL, lobjADOConnection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly '<===here
If Not lobjADOData.BOF Then
    lobjADOData.MoveFirst
    Do While Not lobjADOData.EOF
        DoEvents
        .
        .
        .
```

or if you just want to dump the data into a worksheet

```
Dim lobjTargetSheet As Worksheet

Set lobjTargetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("<SomeSheetName>")
With lobjTargetSheet
    .Select
    .Range("1:" & .UsedRange.Rows.count + 1).Delete xlUp
    .Range("A1").Select
    .Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset lobjADOData
End With
```

Comment: can you give some sytanx to it